# Broken Pipe when Using Python Multiprocessing Managers (BaseManager/SyncManager) to Share Queue with Remote Machines

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe

In the last month, we've had a persistent problem with the Python 2.6.x multiprocessing package when we've tried to use it to share a queue among several different (linux) computers.  I've posed this question directly to Jesse Noller as well since we haven't yet found anything that elucidates the issue on StackOverflow, Python docs, source code or elsewhere online.

Our team of engineers hasn't been able to solve this one, and we've posed the question to quite a few people in python user groups to no avail. I was hoping someone could shed some insight, since I feel like we're doing something incorrect but are too close to the problem to see it for what it is.

Here's the symptom:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/django_root/dev/com/brightscope/data/processes/daemons/deferredupdates/servers/queue_server.py", line 65, in get_from_queue
    return queue, queue.get(block=False)
  File "<string>", line 2, in get
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

(I'm showing where our code calls queue.get() on a shared queue object, hosted by a manager that extends SyncManger).

What's peculiar about the issue is that if we connect to this shared queue on a single machine (let's call this `machine A`), even from lots of concurrent processes, we never seem to run into an issue. It's only when we connect to the queue (again, using a class that extends multiprocessing SyncManager and currently adds no additional functionality) from other machines (let's call these `machines B and C`) and run a high volume of items into and out of the queue at the same time that we experience a problem.

It is as though python's multiprocessing package handles local connections (even though they are still using the same manager.connect() connection method) in a manner that works from `machine A` but when remote connections are made simultaneously from at least one of `machines B or C` we get a Broken pipe error.

In all the reading my team has done, we thought the problem was related to locking.  We thought maybe we shouldn't use `Queue.Queue`, but instead `multiprocessing.Queue`, but we switched and the problem persisted (we also noticed that SyncManager's own shared Queue is an instance of Queue.Queue).

We are pulling our hair out about how to even debug the issue, since it's hard to reproduce but does happen fairly frequently (many times per day if we are inserting and .get()ing lots of items from the queue).

The method we created `get_from_queue` attempts to retry acquiring the item from a queue ~10 times with randomized sleep intervals, but it seems like if it fails once, it will fail all ten times (which lead me to believe that .register() and .connect()ing to a manager perhaps doesn't give another socket connection to the server, but I couldn't confirm this either by reading the docs or looking at the Python internal source code).

Can anyone provide any insight into where we might look or how we might track what's actually happening?

How can we start a new connection in the event of a broken pipe using `multiprocessing.BaseManager` or `multiprocessing.SyncManager`?

How can we prevent the broken pipe in the first place?

Comment: I ran into the same problem, in my case it was caused by a mistake where main program exit too early and multiprocessing.Process instances are still running in the background.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

FYI In case anyone else runs by this same error, after extensive consulting with Ask Solem and Jesse Noller of Python's core dev team, it looks like this is actually a bug in current python 2.6.x (and possibly 2.7+ and possibly 3.x).  They are looking at possible solutions and a fix will probably be included in a future version of Python.

Comment: Is there a Python bug report for this?

Comment: Was this ever fixed? I'm seeing a similar issue with Python 3.8.0.

Comment: I'm getting similar issue in 3.10

Answer (score 8):

I have suffered from the same problem, even if connecting on localhost in python 2.7.1. After a day of debugging i found the cause and a workaround:

Cause: BaseProxy class has thread local storage which caches the connection, which is reused for future connections causing "broken pipe" errors even on creating a new Manager

Workaround:
Delete the cached connection before reconnecting. Add the code to a try-except clause on the line which raises the exception, and then retry it.

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseProxy

...

if address in BaseProxy._address_to_local:
    del BaseProxy._address_to_local[address][0].connection
```

The `address` is the hostname/ip used to connect to the multiprocessing Manager. If you have not explicitly set it, it should usually be `"localhost"`

Comment: What file/line would I add this change?

Comment: I'm also trying to understand this.  Where does address come from?

Comment: Add this line in your code just before the line which raises the exception for you, or add it in a try/except block around your operations and retry.

Comment: I have the same question as @mudda above. It's not clear what address is in this context. Also needed imports for this to work would be nice.

Comment: Yes it'is work for me on linux-sockets (files) connection and SyncManager. I use it for communication of two different process and sharing data in dict.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the cpu memory is enough to support the program. I just increased the allocated memory and the broken pipe error was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try to catch the exception in the child processes, so that it should not try to close the connection UN-expectedly. Same was happening to me and finally I had to suppress the errors so that the pipe should not get close abruptly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in an interactive Jupyter notebook (Python 3.6.8) after interrupting a multiprocessing process.

My short term fix was **reinstantiating the `Manager` and `Namespace` objects**:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager

mgr = Manager()
ns = mgr.Namespace()
```

From the [guide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html):

> **Avoid terminating processes**
>
> Using the Process.terminate method to stop a process is liable to
>   cause any shared resources (such as locks, semaphores, pipes and
>   queues) currently being used by the process to become broken or
>   unavailable to other processes.
>
> Therefore it is probably best to only consider using Process.terminate
>   on processes which never use any shared resources.