# multiprocessing broken pipe after a long time

Tags: python, multiprocessing, broken-pipe

I develop a crawler using multiprocessing model.

which use multiprocessing.Queue to store url-infos which need to crawl , page contents which need to parse and something more;use multiprocessing.Event to control sub processes;use multiprocessing.Manager.dict to store hash of crawled url;each multiprocessing.Manager.dict instance use a multiprocessing.Lock to control access.

All the three type params are shared between all sub processes and parent process, and all the params are organized in a class, I use the instance of the class to transfer shared params from parent process to sub process. Just like:

    `MGR = SyncManager()
    class Global_Params():
        Queue_URL = multiprocessing.Queue()
        URL_RESULY = MGR.dict()
        URL_RESULY_Mutex = multiprocessing.Lock()
        STOP_EVENT = multiprocessing.Event()
    global_params = Global_Params()`

In my own timeout mechanism, I  use process.terminate to stop the process which can't stop by itself for a long time!

In my test case, there are 2500+ target sites(some are unservice, some are huge).
crawl site by site that in the target sites file.

At the begining the crawler could work well, but after a long time( sometime 8 hours, sometime 2 hours, sometime moer then 15 hours), the crawler has crawled moer than 100( which is indeterminate) sites, I'll get error info:"Errno 32 broken pipe"

I have tried the following methods to location and solve the problems:

1. location the site A which crawler broken on, then use crawler to crawls the site separately, the crawler worked well. Even I get a fragment(such as 20 sites) from all the target sites file which contain the site A, the crawler worked well!
2. add "-X /tmp/pymp-* 240 /tmp" to /etc/cron.daily/tmpwatch
3. when Broken occured the file /tmp/pymp-* is still there
4. use multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager replace multiprocessing.Manager and ignore most signal except SIGKILL and SIGTERM
5. for each target site, I clear most shared params(Queues,dicts and event),if error occured, create a new instance:

`while global_params.Queue_url.qsize()>0:
        try:
            global_params.Queue_url.get(block=False)
        except Exception,e:
            print_info(str(e))
            print_info("Clear Queue_url error!")
            time.sleep(1)
            global_params.Queue_url = Queue()
            pass`

  the following is the Traceback info, the print_info function is defined to print and store debug info by myself:

    `[Errno 32] Broken pipe
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Spider.py", line 613, in <module>
    main(args)
    File "Spider.py", line 565, in main
    spider.start()
    File "Spider.py", line 367, in start
    print_info("STATIC_RESULT size:%d" % len(global_params.STATIC_RESULT))
    File "<string>", line 2, in __len__
    File "/usr/local/python2.7.3/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 769, in _callmethod
    kind, result = conn.recv()
    EOFError`

  I can't understand why, does anyone knows the reason?

Comment: It seems that you don't have enough memory for what you are trying to process. You'll need to find a way to free what you don't need to use anymore.

Comment: When the crawler hang, I checked the memory, there are still 10G memory is free(totally 16G), and in the crowler I cleared each Queue and dict in every loop.

Comment: It might be the systems that is killing your process since it's been running for so long. You might need to configure extra privileges for it on your system.

Comment: Yes, my privileges is a normal user not root, but I can use "sudo" to excute python. I don't know how to config the extra privilege, could you give an example?

Comment: It is not about sudo privileges. It's about your process runner. I'm not sure how to configure that but I'm pretty sure that it's the one that causing all the trouble.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Excute "ulimit -a", I find the max user processes is 1024. But I think there still other reason for the broken pipe. I am trying the method： http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649458/broken-pipe-when-using-python-multiprocessing-managers-basemanager-syncmanager  . Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that is fixing your problem, but there is one point to mention:

```
global_params.Queue_url.get(block=False)
```

... throws an Queue.Empty expeption, if the Queue is empty. It's not worth to recreate the Queue for an empty exception.

The recreation of the queue can lead to race conditions.

From my point of view, you have to possibilities:

1. get rid of the "queue recreation" code block
2. switch to an other Queue implementation

use:

```
from Queue import Queue
```

instead of:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
```

Comment: Yes. Because the code is in test stage, I am not paying attention to details now. Thank you.

Comment: yeah i see. but this can lead to race conditions. i've edited my answer.

Comment: yeah, but Queue.Queue can't be shared between processes in my remember, I have tested.

Comment: then try to avoid the recreation of the queue, if empty.

Comment: yeah, have done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649458/broken-pipe-when-using-python-multiprocessing-managers-basemanager-syncmanager I think @pankaj may be right, but I'm not sure the place where the code should be insert. I could't connect him, my reputation is too low.