# multiprocessing.Queue seems to go away? OS (pipe destruction) vs Python?

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing

I'm using multiprocessing.queues.JoinableQueue as follows:

A very long-running thread (multiple days) polls an API for XML.  The thread that does this simply parses the XML into objects and shoves these into the queue.

The handling of each object takes significantly more time than parsing the XML and in no way depends on the thread reading from the API.  As such this implementation of multiprocessing is reather simple.

The code for creating and cleaning up processes is here:

```
    def queueAdd(self, item):
        try:
            self.queue.put(item)
        except AssertionError:
            #queue has been closed, remake it (let the other GC)
            logger.warn('Queue closed early.')
            self.queue = BufferQueue(ctx=multiprocessing.get_context())
            self.queue.put(item)
        except BrokenPipeError:
            #workaround for pipe issue
            logger.warn('Broken pipe, Forcing creation of new queue.')
            # all reading procesess should suicide and new ones spawned.
            self.queue = BufferQueue(ctx=multiprocessing.get_context())
#             address = 'localhost'
#             if address in multiprocessing.managers.BaseProxy._address_to_local:
#                 del BaseProxy._address_to_local[address][0].connection
            self.queue.put(item)
        except Exception as e:
            #general thread exception.
            logger.error('Buffer queue exception %s' % e)
            #TODO: continue trying/trap exceptions?
            raise
        # check for finished consumers and clean them up before we check to see
        # if we need to add additional consumers.
        for csmr in self.running:
            if not csmr.is_alive():
                debug('Child dead, releasing.')
                self.running.remove(csmr)

        #see if we should start a consumer...
        # TODO: add min/max processes (default and override)
        if not self.running:
            debug('Spawning consumer.')
            new_consumer = self.consumer(
                    queue=self.queue,
                    results_queue=self.results_queue,
                    response_error=self.response_error)
            new_consumer.start()
            self.running.append(new_consumer)
```

The consumer processes control loop is pretty simple as well:

```
    def run(self):
        '''Consumes the queue in the framework, passing off each item to the
        ItemHandler method.
        '''
        while True:
            try:
                item = self.queue.get(timeout=3)
                #the base class just logs this stuff
                rval = self.singleItemHandler(item)
                self.queue.task_done()
                if rval and self.results_queue:
                    self.results_queue.put(rval)
            except queue.Empty:
                logging.debug('Queue timed out after 3 seconds.')
                break
            except EOFError:
                logging.info(
                    '%s has finished consuming queue.' % (__class__.__name__))
                break
            except Exception as e:
                #general thread exception.
                self.logger.error('Consumer exception %s' % e)
                #TODO: continue trying/trap exceptions?
                raise
```

After a while (about an hour of successful processing), I get a log message indicating that the consumer process has died due to timing out `DEBUG:root:Queue timed out after 3 seconds.`, but the queue is still open and apparently still being written to by the original thread.  The thread doesn't seem to think that the consumer process has terminated (see the queueAdd method) and doesn't attempt to start a new one.  The queue does not appear to be empty, simply reading from it appears to have timed out.

I'm at a loss for why the manager thinks the child is still alive.

Edit

---

I have modified the original question due to a code change to how the BrokenPipeError is logged as well as to remove the broken connection cleanup.  I consider that a separate issue.

Comment: While carefully reviewing this issue, I realized that I didn't have logging output for the BrokenPipe exception outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649458/broken-pipe-when-using-python-multiprocessing-managers-basemanager-syncmanager

Comment: I've added additional logging as noted in the comment above, but after another test got no log message concerning the BrokenPipeError.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was being caused by a subtle reality with multiprocessing.Queue.  ANY process which called queue.put will be running a background thread that writes to the named pipe.

In my particular case, while there isn't a significant amount of data being posted to the results queue (items that couldn't be handled for some reason) it was still enough to 'fill up' the pipe and cause the consumer to fail to exit even though it wasn't running.  This in turn lead to the writing queue filling up slowly.

The solution is that I modified my non-blocking call for the next iteration of the api calls to read all of the results available so far except on the last (blocking) call which ensures that all results are fetched.

```
def finish(self, block=True, **kwargs):
    '''
    Notifies the buffer that we are done filling it.
    This command binds to any processes still running and lets them
    finish and then copies and flushes the managed results list.
    '''
    # close the queue and wait until it is consumed
    if block:
        self.queue.close()
        self.queue.join_thread()
        # make sure the consumers are done consuming the queue
        for csmr in self.running:
            #get everything on the results queue right now.
            try:
                while csmr.is_alive():
                    self.results_list.append(
                        self.results_queue.get(timeout=0.5))
                    self.results_queue.task_done()
            except queue.Empty:
                if csmr.is_alive():
                    logger.warn('Result queue empty but consumer alive.')
                    logger.warn('joining %s.' % csmr.name)
                    csmr.join()
        del self.running[:]
        if self.callback:
            return self.callback(self.results_list)
    else:
        #read results immediately available.
        try:
            while True:
                self.results_list.append(self.results_queue.get_nowait())
                self.results_queue.task_done()
        except queue.Empty:
            #got everything on the queue so far
            pass
    return self.results_list
```